# Ruby ActiveRecord validation based on existing value in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know the common ways of validation in Ruby.
My current problem is, I would like the insert to fail if the record exists with boolean set to true. Example
Columns in table are => Name, Address, Has_changed, id

Now if has_changed is set to true in table, I would like to add new entry in the table (in a separate call) which will have name, Address (new one), has_changed(set to false) and id. I would not like to update existing entry as I want to keep history for the record.

Is there a way to have such a validation by using Ruby?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you find if has_changed is true?

Comment: @techvineet `TableName.where(:has_changed => true)`?

Comment: No, how will you find that the last record has has_changed => true? The new record will have same Name as the last record?

Comment: Do you mean Table.where(:table_name=>'name', :has_changed=>true) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think its better use "new" and "create" actions in your controller

```
class RecordsController < BaseController
  def new
    @record = Record.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    Record.create(params[:record])
  end
end
```

Your form just contains adress

In your model make a before_create hook

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_value_for :has_changed, false
  before_create :check_changed

  ...

  private

  def check_changed
    changed_record = Record.where(name: name, has_changed: false).first
    if changed_record && (changed_record.address != address)
      changed_record.has_changed = true
      changed_record.save
    end
  end
end
```

And add a validation for address to avoid duplication